# mysql SELECT ( need to connect to 2 tables and show results for a search )

Tags: php, mysql, search, phpmyadmin

I want to connect 2 tables in my query to show results.
I have `lastname`, `firstname` etc in the first table.
In the second table I have `training`, `date`...

I also have in the second table an `ID` reference that links lastname and firstname to training and date.
So whenever I create a training record into the database it uses the same ID for the same person.
I want to be able to connect both tables in my query and show results if I search for `lastname`.
It will also list all the training that they have completed if I click there name in the search that came up.
I am very new at MySQL database.
I am using phpmyadmin for MySQL and running a localhost database for testing purposes...
I currently can search a single table and bring up results, but I cannot figure out the union to link them and have the names list as a link to show there training. and having it keep there name at the top for a printout... here is the code I am using that I got from a tutorial.

```
    <form>
  <div align="right">
    <input type="button" value="Print Results" onClick="myprint()">
  </div>
</form>
<?php

// TAKE THE INFORMATION FROM FORM.
$search = $_GET['search'];

// IF THERE IS NOT A KEYWORD GIVE AN ERROR
if (!$search) 
echo "You didn't enter a keyword";
else
{
  echo "<td>You searched for: <strong>$search </strong></td>";
  mysql_connect('localhost','loginid','password');
  mysql_select_db('trainingrecords');  
  $id=@$_GET['id'];

  //QUERY IS THE CODE WHICH WILL MAKE THE SEARCH IN YOUR DATABASE.
  //I WROTE AN EXPLANATION ABOUT IT AFTER THE CODE.  
  $query="SELECT * FROM username 
          WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, created) 
          AGAINST('%$search%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
  $result1 = MySQL_query($query);  
  if(!$result1) {  
    echo MySQL_error()."<br>$query<br>";
  }  
  if (MySQL_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    echo "<table width='750' align='center' border='1' 
           cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>";
    while($result2 = MySQL_fetch_array($result1)) {

      //A short description from category.
      $description = $result2['location'];
      $searchPosition = strpos($description, $search);
      $shortDescription = substr($description, $searchPosition, 150);

      echo "<td><strong>{$result2['lastname']} 
            {$result2['firstname']}</td></strong><td>
            $shortDescription</td><td>{$result2['created']}</td><tr/>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
    echo "No Results were found in this category.<br>";
  } 
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- You have an SQL injection hole**
Make sure to escape all your variables using `mysql_real_escape_string`
And make use to properly quote string inside the query _(otherwise mysql_real_escape_string will not work)_

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($GET['search']);
....
$query="SELECT * FROM username 
      WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, created) 
      AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
//            ^             ^ quotes were already there, good!
```

**2- If you want to get results from multiple tables you'll have to do a join**

```
$search = "SELECT u.*, t.* FROM username u
  INNER JOIN training t ON (u.id = t.user_id)
  WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, created) 
        AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Normally you do not want to select all the fields, If you explicitly state the fields you want show to the user, the query will run faster.

Here's a decent tutorial on php and MySQL: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/
And here's what happens if you have SQL-injection holes: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Comment: Thanks Johan this works great! Now my only issue is my string search. when I search lastname and if there are two people with same last name is brings them both up and when I search firstname lastname together. it seems to ignore it and just pulls both up anyways. How can I get it to Match only the firstname and lastname on my search. rather than just looking for both and giving me all results?

Comment: I also am having trouble ordering the search by lastname or whichever I choose. Is there a way to have my table with headers for each field that if you click them it orders them by that field? and have the default being lastname?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM username, training
    where username.lastname = $lastname and username.firstname = $firstname
        and username.id = training.id;
```

which would require you to pass in your `$lastname` and `$firstname` values as separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Its not union its join you want

```
Select a.id,a.firstname,a.lastname,a.location,a.date,b.trainingdate 
from username a
inner join
training b on a.id=b.id
```

Add your where clause on the end

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
$query="SELECT * FROM username u LEFT JOIN training t on (t.userid = u.id) WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, created) AGAINST('%$search%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- something basic like this?

SELECT u.id, u.name, t.link
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trainings t ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE u.id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT username.* FROM username
JOIN training ON (training.id = username.id)
WHERE MATCH( lastname, firstname, location, created)    
      AGAINST('%$search%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```